# Subtract time in text format

Tags: time

I have two columns in excel and want to subtract the time difference in minutes
21/12/2022, 8:17 pm
21/12/2022, 8:00 pm

How can I convert text to a number format so that I can subtract those easily

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VALUE function. The VALUE function converts a text string that represents a number to a number value.
For example, to convert the text "8:17" to a number value, you can use the following formula:

```
=VALUE("8:17")
```

This will return a number value equivalent to the time 8:17.

To subtract the time difference between two cells in Excel, you can use the =B2-A2 formula, where A2 and B2 are the cells containing the two times you want to subtract.

You can also use the =TEXT function to convert the result of the subtraction back to a text string in a desired format, if needed. For example, to convert the result to a time format, you can use the following formula:

```
=TEXT(B2-A2, "h:mm")
```

This will return the time difference in the format "hh:mm".